# "can't return a result set in the given context" error when calling stored procedure - differences between mysql 5.0 and 5.5?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a [stored procedure](https://gist.github.com/4692790#file-edgelisttonestedset-sql) to regenerate leafs (nleft, nright) in simple (id, id_parent) tree. ([sample table](https://gist.github.com/4692790#file-data-sql))

When I'am calling

```
CALL EdgeListToNestedSet( 'category', 'id_category', 'id_parent');
```

it works great with version **5.5.29** of mysql but on **5.0.26**  I've got an error:

```
#1312 - PROCEDURE test.EdgeListToNestedSet can't return a result set in the given context
```

Any ideas what can be wrong and how to make it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Older versions of phpMyAdmin have issues with MySQL. [**This has been asked 8 times in `StackOverflow` with the tag `mysql-error-1312`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1312?sort=newest&pagesize=50).

[This bug was seen and addressed in MySQL 5.0.09 beta](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=24485) about 6 weeks after [MySQL 5.0.26 was released Oct 09, 2006](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?3,120203,120203#msg-120203). Still, you got this error.

According to http://qasimbadami.wordpress.com/tag/mysql-error-1312/, you should make sure you are using mysqli / PDO.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too; calling the procedure worked on my local xampp instalation but not on the live server.

Tried a lot of things and pulled a lot of hair on this one.

I was concatenating some strings in the procedure, on different rows for clarity; after i put all the text of the concat statement on a single row it worked (deleted only white space, no  code); so it might be that some special new line characters break something in MySQL concatenations